# Spring Boot can convert Xml response body to Java object, but can't convert Java object to Xml request body

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

When i am trying to send a request with the content-type `application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.session+xml;version=5.6` spring boot gives the below exception:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException:
>   Could not write
>   request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type
>   **[com.vmware.vcloud.v1.SessionType]** and content type
>   **[application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.session+xml;version=5.6]**

But when i get a response from the server **with the same content-type** spring-boot successfully converts the response to `SessionType` object.

Why spring boot gives the above exception when i am trying send a request?

Comment: What happens if you would try to send with content-type 'application/xml' ? 
The reason was quite clearly described : 'no suitable HttpMessageConverter found' . 
I can guess when you get response then spring boot uses HttpMessageConverter same as for 'application/xml' content type

Comment: @yvs When i change the content-type to application/xml, i get the following error. no suitable  HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.vmware.vcloud.v1.SessionType] and content type [application/xml]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` can read classes that are annotated with `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlType`.

But it can write only classes that are annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. Since my classes are not annotated with `@XmlRootElement` its canWrite method returns `false`.

```
@Override
public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class) || clazz.isAnnotationPresent(XmlType.class)) &&
            canRead(mediaType);
}

@Override
public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, XmlRootElement.class) != null && canWrite(mediaType));
}
```